# Autoplay for USB drive keeps popping up

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate external 2TB USB drive that when I leave it plugged in, the Autoplay dialog asking what to do with the drive pops up about once every 30-60 minutes.  No matter how many times I tell it to go away, it keeps coming back.

I have tried multiple power supplies, USB cables, and all the USB ports on my machine...but it keeps doing the same thing.

Also, this does not happen with the same drive on a different computer.

Could this be some power or configuration setting that is causing this?

I'm running Windows 7 x64 (the computer it works on is x86)

Answer (score 1):

This is typically due to a power configuration option. Go into device manager and don't allow the computer to put the device to sleep!

[image]

If this doesn't work, try playing with the power options in Control Panel

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay was constantly popping up when I have tried to watch movie from my new USB external disc connected to USB 3.0 port. I checked out all solutions from changing autoplay settings, USB root Hub settings in "Device manager", power settings, changing registry and nothing helped me until I found one post which helped me.

This is the only solution which helped me and so far doesn't have any problems.

1. Install new USB 3.0 drivers from Intel's web site. Here is the URL of setup exe file:
   http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19880/eng/USB3.0_allOS_2.1.28.1_PV.exe
2. When drivers are installed you will get "USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver" folder in your Start Menu. There is shortcut "USB 3.0 Host Controller Utility", click on it and just check "Disable USB 3.0 power management function" check box.
3. After that everything is working fine with. Now I can play movies from my new USB external disc 2TB. Autoplay window is not popping up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

may be your computers usb port has a problem ?? did you tried different usb ports? or may be electrical problem?? i do not think it is a software problem but it can be a virus problem? or as i experienced lately if it is a fat32 format and i try to do several copying data to and from that hdd at the same time it gives error and ejects itself then aoutoplay pop up .. like your problem... (if the format of hdd is different from ntfs you should format it to ntfs)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\AutoPlay you should be able to control what AutoPlay options are avalible. Or you could turn off autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your auto-play settings, you need to shut down and restart your computer WITHOUT removing/ejecting your hard-drive from PC.
If you remove your hard-drive before shutting down, the modifications in the settings reset. This is a bug in Windows which keeps existing for years.